# Use JQuery slice() and appendTo() to show data in another div

Tags: jquery, html, append, slice

I have this code structure:

```
<div class="social-1"></div>

<div class="social-feed-container">
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
 <div class="social-feed-element"></div>
</div>
```

I need the first three divs with the class social-feed-element to be sliced off this list and shown in the div with the class social-1. Here is my JQuery but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
     splitThree();
 });

function splitThree() {
    var firstThree = $(".social-feed-element");
    for (var i = 0; i < firstThree.length; i += 3) {
        firstThree.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
        $("<div class='new'></div>").appendTo('.social-1'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Can you give some more description on "does not seem to work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct methods, you're just making the code a lot more complicated than it needs to be. You can achieve what you require in a single line.

Your code example also seems to be attempting to wrap the elements in another container despite the description not mentioning that behaviour. If you also need this, you can use `wrapAll()`:

```js
$('.social-feed-container .social-feed-element').slice(0, 3).appendTo('.social-1').wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
```

```css
.social-1, .social-feed-container {
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
.new {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social-1"></div>

<div class="social-feed-container">
  <div class="social-feed-element">1</div>
  <div class="social-feed-element">2</div>
  <div class="social-feed-element">3</div>
  <div class="social-feed-element">4</div>
  <div class="social-feed-element">5</div>
  <div class="social-feed-element">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was attempting to wrap it because none of my code seemed to be working. :( I tried your code and this also seems to not work. The social feed is a plugin I am using to show twitter and fb posts from my social accounts. Should I try to do this on window load and not document ready you think because it is a plugin? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: As you can see from the snippet above, this works fine on elements available in the DOM when the page loads. It's most likely not working in your case as the plugin is dynamically adding the elements well after the document.ready event has fired. I'd suggest checking their documentation for an event you can hook to, to know when it's finished its work. If there isn't one, then you'll probably have to just use a `setTimeout()` to run your logic on a set delay

Comment: So on window load it seemed to work! :) Thanks! I guess because on document ready the data from the plugin is not there yet.